# Simple HTML preprocessor for "compile time"

Tags: php, html, preprocessor

my question is, is there a preprocessor for HTML like php which runs not when a user does a call. It needs to run at some kind of build stage to do some includes an so on to make some modular HTML pages (nav in one file, footer in an other file and some real page files which are including the footer and nav file) so that I only need to change the nav content and the nav is changed on all "real" pages

Comment: you can use PHP as preprocessor where instead of outputing html you can save it as file

Comment: You mean something like a template engine - a quick search shows up https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/847/top-7-best-open-source-php-template-engines might be interesting to read.

Comment: yes, it's called php-cli